# How to exclude a category from the category list widget for non admin users

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy, woocommerce-theming

I'm trying to exclude `one category` from the category list widget on the `Shop` and `product archive` pages for `users other than the administrator`. But for some reason it doesn't work.

Any help, thanks.

```
function exclude_category( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {
    $new_terms = array();

    /*if ( !is_admin()  && ( is_product() || is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ) ){ */
    if ( !is_admin() || is_product() || is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag()  ){  
        foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
            if( is_object ( $term ) ) {
                if ( 'some-category' == $term->slug && $term->taxonomy = 'product_cat' ) {
                    unset($terms[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $terms;
}
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'exclude_category', 10, 3 );
```

I was inspired by this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48849931/16275280

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Excluding a product category on WooCommerce

Use the following conditional checks instead:

- To check whether a user is admin or not, you could use the `roles` property of the user object returned from [`wp_get_current_user`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/) function.
- To check whether you're on woocommerce pages or not (i.e `is_product() || is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag()`), you could simply use this `is_woocommerce()` function.

So the entire code would be:

```php
add_filter('get_terms', 'exclude_category', 10, 3);

function exclude_category($terms, $taxonomies, $args)
{
    $roles = wp_get_current_user()->roles;

    if 
      (
        !in_array('administrator', $roles)
        &&
        is_woocommerce() 
      ) 
    {
        foreach ($terms as $key => $term) 
        {
            if (is_object($term)) 
            {
                if ('decor' == $term->slug && $term->taxonomy == 'product_cat') 
                {
                    unset($terms[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $terms;
}
```

**Note:**

- I've used `'decor'` as the category slug to test this snippet on my site, so don't forget to replace it with your own category slug.

And here's the result:

[image]

---

#### Excluding a category on Wordpress

```php
add_filter('get_terms', 'exclude_category', 10, 3);

function exclude_category($terms, $taxonomies, $args)
{
    $roles = wp_get_current_user()->roles;

    if (
        !in_array('administrator', $roles)
       ) 
    {
        foreach ($terms as $key => $term) 
        {
            if (is_object($term)) 
            {
                if ('uncategorized' == $term->slug && $term->taxonomy == 'category') 
                {
                    unset($terms[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $terms;
}
```

**Note:**

- I've used `'uncategorized'` as the category slug to test this snippet on my site, so don't forget to replace it with your own category slug.

---

#### Excluding multiple categories in WooCommerce

You could set up an array and use `in_array` function for the conditional check. Like this:

```php
$excluded_cat_slugs = array ('hoodies', 'decor');  

if(in_array($term->slug, $excluded_cat_slugs) && $term->taxonomy == 'product_cat')
```

---

#### Excluding multiple categories in Wordpress

```php
$excluded_cat_slugs = array ('uncategorized', 'test-category');  

if(in_array($term->slug, $excluded_cat_slugs) && $term->taxonomy == 'category')
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Can I exclude several categories in this way?  `if ( array ( 'uncategorized', 'decor', 'hoodies' )  == $term->slug && $term->taxonomy = 'category')`

Comment: Not a problem! You could use an array but not exactly like that! I've updated my answer. Please read the last section of my answer.

Comment: Thank you, that helped. Can I ask you to take a look at my question from another thread? Please https://stackoverflow.com/a/70827321/16275280

Comment: Sure I will when I get a chance! Looks like there are lots of details involved.

Comment: I have a problem. When I use your code, the seller data disappears on the product pages.

Comment: The code I provided you with, executes only inside the terms/categories filter. So, what is a seller? Are you using `dokan` plugin on top of woocommerce? What does a category filter have to do with a seller data? If you think it's related to the snippet code I provided you with or you need assistance, please explain every single details so that I'll try to help you debug your app!

Comment: I think this is going to be very difficult, so I'll try to figure it out on my own for now.